# How to counter oddities of Shade-Tree Checkers? (long distance king jumps, etc)

Tags: variants, checkers

I know someone who played checkers with a guy, and he plays with non-standard rules. People he plays with have their own rules, in this case, he played where the kinged checkers piece can jump unlimited distance and land just past the single piece being jumped. For example, given the below board, with `W`hite and `B`lack kings

```
___________
|  B    W
|W  
|  B
|
```

Normally, `W`hite's only jump move would be with the left piece jumping the lower `B`lack, but in this variation, the top right `W`hite can make a jump down-left just past the lower `B`lack.

I don't hold much hope that you would know these particular rules, since they were probably made up on the fly and talked into acceptance.

What would you suggest, as how to defeat someone who is used to this.. but not by forcing him into the standard rules.

- Is there online reading material regarding obscure game variants?
- Is there a way to get a computer to follow unusual rules, allowing me to get some practice ahead of time? (at least with the special rules I'm aware of) I am a programmer, but I was hoping for something that required less programming and maybe something more generic, where I can just set the rules and play on a higher level.
- Do you have other suggestions on how to level the playing field, so I can fare better in checkers with this opponent?

I am hoping to get in as much practice ahead of time before, to reduce the need to learn on the fly.

I play Chess very well already.

Comment: To level the playing field you could change more of the rules, so that neither of you are familiar with the game?  Maybe not most constructive of comments :-)

Comment: "Long-jumping" kings are standard in international checkers: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_checkers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variant of checkers described here is most likely [Pool Checkers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pool_checkers), or is at least closely related. A quick Google search showed several [online play](http://www.ludoteka.com/pool_checkers.html) sites along with general strategy write-ups. There is even an [iPad app](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/pool-checkers/id534569191?mt=8) with VS Computer play.

Having never played the variant myself, I cannot give any specific advice on gameplay improvements.